# Is it possible to send data from a class to another class (not an acitivity) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, class, android-intent

I don't want to send data from an activity to another one .
the error i get is this :

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,LogOut.class) ;
```

Can't resolve constructor Intent !!!

Comment: why don't you put it in the constructor, or may be call a method or maybe send it through an interface?

Comment: This kind of way is only used for Activities. Why don't you use preferred storage options?

Comment: Either add an import `import android.content.Intent` or `this` is not an instance of `Context`

Comment: You don't need intent here (as you said it is a not activity class),  you can just create `Logout` object.

Comment: Are you use this code in fragment ? user ActivityName.this instead of only this

Comment: I have been able to access data from other objects but I read somewhere that it works as long as they run on the same thread.  I haven't tried testing the opposite.

Comment: You need to show us some actual code that illustrate your problem. It's unclear why you can't just pass the data through a method or to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables globally then create getter, setter for the declared variables. So you can get the variable's value in any other class you want by getter method.

```
public class GetSet2 {

    public GetSet2(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what you want to do exactly. It is not possible to use an intent to do that. check the definition of intent http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
You can use set and get of the class. and if you want to save the data of your activity you can use shared preferences. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

example:  in your first class:

```
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("Name", n);
        editor.putString("Phone", ph);
        editor.putString("Email", e);
        editor.commit();
```

In the second:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String imgSett = prefs.getString("Name", "");
```

.......................

Take care using the Context. if you are using activity this for non activity use a context.

Comment: I have 2 classes , Log_In and Log_out , and i want to send the the variable ID from the class Log_in to the class Log_out so I can send the data To My server (it need to be the same ID ,coz i want to show data when a person logout ) .